# bind a module level variable to an instance variable

Tags: python

I'm trying to refactor a module where users modify a module level variable. I want to remove this variable internally and replace it with a class. Currently users do something like the following:

```
from module import T
T = 'some value'
```

I was trying to see if it possible to keep this same usage pattern and essentially bind this module level variable to my new class to avoid any braking changes in client code, but the values don't stay in sync.

```
# some dummy class with a property
class A: 
    def __init__(self, p): 
        self.p = p 
                                                                                                                 

serv = A('a')                                                                                                   

# the property has a value of 'a'
serv.p                                                                                                          
>>>'a'

# Make T equal to that of serv.p
T = serv.p                                                                                                      

T                                                                                                               
>>>'a'

# But updating the other variable doesn't update the property
T = 'c'                                                                                                         

T                                                                                                               
>>>'c'

serv.p                                                                                                         
>>>'a'
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible in python?

Comment: Strings are passed by value in python, so `T` is simply a copy of `serv.p`. There isn't any way to do this because you can't overload assignment in python. You could make `p` a class, and then `T` is a reference to the same object; changing `T` would then change `p` (but assigning `T` still wouldn't).

Comment: `from module import T; T = 'some value'` won't work either: the value of `T` inside `module` won't change

Answer (score 1):

No, when you use `T = serv.p` it makes a copy of `serv.p` in `T`. So you can't modify `serv.p` using `T`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution that used the property decorator.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, p):
        self._p = p

    @property
    def p(self):
         import module
         if module.T and not self._p:
             self._p = module.T
         return self._p
    @p.setter
    def p(self, value):
         import module
         self._p = value
         module.T = value
```

this only works as in the client code they import like the following

```
import module
module.T = 'some value'
```

but works well enough for my use case.